# rails add new item to specific position in list (above or below)

Tags: mysql, css, list, ruby-on-rails-4, position

In rails 4 I have a list of todo items where I can add a new todo item and it will display in descending order on my project show page.

I'd like to be able to add a new todo item at a specific position, with the option of adding it above or below an existing todo item with the use of an add button. I would then like this set position to be stored in the database (MySQL)

I imagine I can use some basic css to create a show on hover for the button and I've added a position column to my todo item, but I can't seem to figure out the best way to go about adding a todo item to a specific position.

I've watched the 'Sortable Lists' Railscasts and have been scouring the web for something more specific without any luck.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You should take a look at [acts_as_list](https://github.com/swanandp/acts_as_list) gem wich provides amoung other methods to :

```
.insert_at(x position)
.move_lower
.move_higher
```